# Do not apply for a visualisation "use as filter" from the other visual - oracle OAS/DV

Tags: oracle-bi

Is it possible to exclude visualisation from "user as filter" feature impact coming from other visual at the same canvas?

I have one visual on the canvas, showing some totals information, that shouldn't change when filter comes from any other visualisation.

On the first pic you can find how is should be, but when i apply other visual as a filter - I'm getting a new filter value "STAGE" (pic2).

[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsLbZ.png)
[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6GL0.png)

**UPD.**
looks like this feature are not developed yet. Please vote for both ideas if someone needs such a feature

https://community.oracle.com/customerconnect/discussion/567761/ability-to-apply-filter-from-viz-to-viz

https://community.oracle.com/customerconnect/discussion/658738/ability-to-tune-use-as-filter-over-its-impact-for-each-viz-on-the-canvas

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that the feature you are looking for is not available yet.

As an alternative, you could disable the "Use as Filter" option and replace it with filters in the global bar or a Dashboard Filters visualization. Then select the visualization that should ignore filters, click on the Filters tab in the Properties pane and tick/untick properties under the Filter this Viz By section as required.